# Creating Real-Time Indexes in Sphinx

Tags: real-time, sphinx, sphinxql

I'm stuck at creating a real-time index with sphinx search engine. I'm following the documentation but I get weird results:

mysql> attach index profile to rtindex rt_profile;

ERROR 1064 (42000): sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected PROFILE, expecting IDENT near 'profile to rtindex rt_profile'

I'm using Sphinx 2.1.2-id64-release (r4245)

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

OK I just figured it out - profile is a key word: ( used in SHOW PROFILE command)